# Why doesn't Java allow overloads based on type parameters?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

We can get away with this in .NET:

```
interface I<A> {}
interface I<A, B> {}
```

... but in Java, the same code will result in a compilation error.

That's interesting, given that even if the type information is gone at runtime, one would expect the information about the number of type parameter to still be there.

If this limitation is related to type erasure, can someone explain why?

Comment: The limitation is you cannot define an interface more than once and you cannot overload it this way. At runtime, type-erasure would ensure both `I` is actually the same type which is not allowed, or technically it wouldn't do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not related to type erasure so much as to the ambiguity that would arise from using the [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html):

```
I eye = null;  // which 'I' is it?
```

Raw types are allowed in order to accommodate code written before generics were introduced in JDK 5.0.

Comment: so the problem is not type erasure per se, just the fact that Java allows the use of raw types which basically amounts to implicitly passing Object as the type argument(s)?

Comment: How does .NET solve this problem? Raw types are not permitted?

Comment: So if Java wanted to solve this, the compiler could issue an "ambiguous type reference" error in this case, the same way as happens with overloaded methods when those get ambiguous.

Comment: ... but then we'd also need a different way to compile things, because right now, there is no way to have two classes with the same name (but different type overloads). For methods, the parameter signature is essentially part of the name, so that takes care of overloading there. No such mechanism for classes (and probably very hard to bolt on now).

Answer (score 1):

In java, a generic class/interface has a fixed number of generic parameters. It's just the way the language is defined.

The closest thing to what you are talking about might be:

```
interface I<A> {}
interface J<A, B> extends I<A> {}
```

an instance of `J` is still assignable to a variable of type `I`.